# Using Cloudflare andanother DNS provider

Tags: dns

Is it possible to use Cloudflare CDN as my provider for all records except MX and use DNS Made Easy for MX only? DNS Made easy has mail forwarding proxy and Cloudflare has HTTP to HTTPS proxy. I want to take use of both. Neither DNS provider can do both.
How would I do this? Should I have Cloudflare only handle A,AAAA records or DNS Made Easy handle only MX and TXT records? I think it would be better if DNS Made Easy handled all records except A,AAAA. Can Cloudflare do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: idk for cloudflare specifically, but I have my domain on one provider & my mail on another. How much control do you have over your entries? If you can change it, test it. MX points to wherever you tell it to, so long as you're covered with your SPF & DKIM. Keep copies of your old entires, just in case.

Comment: Was easier than I thought. Just added domain and switched NS to Cloudflare but kept the MX and TXT records from DNS Made Easy and to my surprise it worked. Just proxied the A records.